# Lazy loading module specify HTTP path

Tags: angular

We are trying to set the lazy loading of modules in our Angular 6 app up, but we are running into the issue that we are using a proxy to load up the app.

The angular app runs on a subfolder of the main domain (http://127.0.0.1:9000/app) and the main domain is managed via a Grunt server that proxies the `app` folder to where Angular builds the files:

```
"outputPath": "../website/dist/generated-app",
```

So the actual file location for the Angular files is http://127.0.0.1:9000/generated-app and the HTML file that gets loaded on http://127.0.0.1:9000/app references the Angular files in `/generated-app`.

The problem that we are now having with the chunks, is that Angular is trying to download the chunks from e.g. http://127.0.0.1:9000/app/0.js, while they are actually located in http://127.0.0.1:9000/generated-app/0.js

How can we tell Angular to download the chunks from the correct location?

Answer (score 3):

You can build your application with the following flags:

ng build --prod --base-href='/generated-app/' --deploy-url='/generated-app/'

That will tell the index.html to preface the calls to the .js with generated-app.